# ContourPlot:show only one of multiple solutions

Tags: plotting

I have two functions with two parameters (p & x). I am looking for the values of "x" that makes the two functions to be equal, varying "p" from 0 to 1. I have two solutions for this implicit solution, but I am only interested on drawing the first solution where there are equal. The problem looks something like this:

```
VF[x_, p_] = 
  50 (1 - p) x + 25 p x + 
   59 (0.044/(1/p)^3.7 + (0.52 (1 - p))/(1/p)^2.7) x^2.7;

VL[x_, p_] = -100 + 
   180 p x - (14 x^2.7)/(1/p)^3.7 + (-1 + 
      p) (-50 x + (17 x^2.7)/(1/p)^2.7);

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@{VF[x, p], VL[x, p]}, {x, 0, 5}], {{p, 1, "p"}, 0.00001, 1}]
```

[image: Two functions, varying "p", with x in the horizontal axis]

Using ContourPlot I get the two curves for "p" within [0,1] and I haven't been able to get rid of the second curve (second solution for each "p") in the plot.

[image: CountourPlot with two solutions for x, varying p from 0 to 1]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: you should show the `ContourPlot` command you used.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
 p[ x_ ] := p /. 
      First@FindRoot[ VF[x, p] - VL[x, p] == 0 , { p, 0.001 }]
 ParametricPlot[{p[x], x}, {x, .5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Note this is somewhat fortuitous that we can pick an initial guess at `p` that consistently yields the first solution..

Another approach is to operate on the graphics generated by contour plot to pull out the lines:

```
 lines = Cases[Normal@First@
    Cases[ContourPlot[ 
       VF[x, p] - VL[x, p] == 0  , {p, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 
           5}], _GraphicsComplex, Infinity], _Line , Infinity];

  GraphicsColumn[
      Graphics[ #  , Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio] & /@ lines]
```

[image]

[image]